# Python os.isfile assert failing

Tags: python

So I'm having problems opening a file for reading, and so I decided to just try an os.isfile assert:

```
from Android_API_Parser import Android_API_Parser
import os.path

assert os.path.isfile("D:\Work\Python Workspace\Android_API_Parser\test.txt")

tester = Android_API_Parser()
tester.setFile("test.txt")
tester.parse()
```

It's failing the assert:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Work\Python Workspace\Android_API_Parser\src\Android_API_Tester.py", line         
    9, in <module>
assert os.path.isfile("D:\Work\Python Workspace\Android_API_Parser\test.txt")
AssertionError
```

I have opened the path to the file I'm trying to open and pasted it below:

```
D:\Work\Python Workspace\Android_API_Parser\test.txt
```

Any ideas as to why it's even failing the assert?  Unless I'm really tired, the file is clearly located there.  I even tried both with "/" and "\", even with escape characters included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), you must escape backslashes with another backslash, use a *raw string*, or use forward slashes. Otherwise, `"\t"` becomes a string that just contains the tab character.

Try any of:

```
assert os.path.isfile("D:\\Work\\Python Workspace\\Android_API_Parser\\test.txt")
assert os.path.isfile(r"D:\Work\Python Workspace\Android_API_Parser\test.txt")
assert os.path.isfile("D:/Work/Python Workspace/Android_API_Parser/test.txt")
assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join("D:", "Work", "Python Workspace",
                                   "Android_API_Parser", "test.txt"))
```

The file may also not be a regular file. Use [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to see if it exists.

You may also have insufficient privileges to see the file, or the file name you expect [may be localized](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/18/1487464.aspx). To debug this, run:

```
path = ["Work", "Python Workspace", "Android_API_Parser", "test.txt"]
f = 'D:'
for p in path:
  f = os.path.join(f, p)
  print(f)
  assert os.path.exists(f)
assert os.path.isfile(f)
```

Comment: I tried it even with escape backslashes. :/

I tried running all four of those asserts individually, and it failed all of them.

Also, I thought it might not like the space in the PATH name, so I got rid of that, and it still didn't like it.

Comment: @TSM: Spaces are perfectly fine in such a path. philag's answer is certainly correct for the question you posted. Perhaps the file really isn't there? Have you tried with a simpler path?

Comment: @TSM Well, it won't work with the version you posted, that's for sure. I updated the answer with a debugging program. What output do you get if you run it?

Comment: Okay, so I managed to get is to recognize the file with these asserts:

assert os.path.isfile("D:/test.txt")
assert os.path.isfile("D:/Work/PythonWorkspace/Android_API_Parser/src/test.txt")

But now it's failing to open the file still:

Reading file: D:/Work/PythonWorkspace/Android_API_Parser/src/test.txt
Error: can't find file or read data

Comment: I got it working.  I must have just been doing the path wrong, though I though I tried all possible combinations of slashes because I knew they're an issue.  Thanks for the help, though!